# Obtaining max and min from dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

Here is a list of columns in my dataframe:

```
a=list(aps1)
a
Out[107]: 
['ID',
 'class',
 'S3',
 'S22',
 'S23',
 'S26_3',
 'S28']
```

Now I'm trying to run a loop which will obtain the Max and min of each of these columns and display an output like:

```
S3, Range in 0 to 100
S22, Range in 50 to 75
```

and so on. For the loop, I've used:

```
for columns in a:
    print(columns + ', Range in ' + round(aps1.columns.min()) + ' to ' + round(aps1.columns.max()))
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

While running only for one variable:

```
print ('S23, Range in ' + round(aps1.S23.min()) + ' to ' + round(aps1.S23.max()))
```

I get:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')
```

Can somebody help me out here please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I know it's not quite what you have asked for, but have you looked the DataFrame.describe() method? It has the benefit of not requiring loops which are more expensive than the vectorised code that pandas/numpy is famous for. Try calling aps1.describe() and looking at that dataframe, you can then use .loc[] on that output.

Comment: Hi, I did. Actually I need to display the range in a gui so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `format`:

```
for c in aps1.columns:
    print ('{}, Range in {} to {}'.format(c, aps1[c].min(), round(aps1[c].max())))
```

---

But better should be use [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) for DataFrame with `min` and `max`:

```
aps1 = pd.DataFrame({'S3':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'S22':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'S23':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'S26':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})

print (aps1)
   S22  S23  S26  S3
0    7    1    5   4
1    8    3    3   5
2    9    5    6   4
3    4    7    9   5
4    2    1    2   5
5    3    0    4   4

df1 = aps1.agg(['min','max']).round()
print (df1)
     S22  S23  S26  S3
min    2    0    2   4
max    9    7    9   5

for c in df1.columns:
    print ('{}, Range in {} to {}'.format(c, s.loc['min', c], s.loc['max', c]))

S22, Range in 2 to 9
S23, Range in 0 to 7
S26, Range in 2 to 9
S3, Range in 4 to 5
```

---

```
for c in aps1.columns:
    print ('{}, Range in {} to {}'.format(c, aps1[c].min(), round(aps1[c].max())))

S22, Range in 2 to 9
S23, Range in 0 to 7
S26, Range in 2 to 9
S3, Range in 4 to 5
```

Comment: hi, jezrael, getting this error for the 2nd suggestion: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method for the 1st suggestion

Comment: @jezrael: there are two mismatched parenthesis after ``min()``

Comment: @DChy - Do you want `min` and `max` of all columns?

Comment: IndexError: tuple index out of range getting this again, and yes max and min of all columns, to be displayed as mentioned.

Comment: Perfect!youre amazing

Comment: @DChy - You are welcome! Btw, maybe better is add some data sample to question ;) Nice weekend!

Comment: HI @jezrael, is it possible to skip the last 2 columns in this loop? just hypothetically, do you have a code for it?

Comment: @DChy - Sure, only change `aps1.columns` to `aps1.columns[:-2]`